# jquery access sibling TD in table

Tags: jquery, html-table, siblings

I have the following HTML Code.  What I'm try to do is to have the div named javaRatingDiv to be displayed once the checkbox with the name java is checked.

I can't seem to figure out how to navigate to the next TD in a table via jquery.

```
<div id="languages">
   <table style="width:inherit">
   <tr style="height:50px; vertical-align:top">
     <td>Select the languages that you are familiar with and rate your knowledge:</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <table style="width:75%;" align="center">   
     <tr id="tableRow"> 
       <td id="firstTD"><input type="checkbox" name="java" value="java" />&nbsp;Java</td>
       <td id="secondTD" style="width:200px;">
         <div id="javaRatingDiv" style="display:none">
           <input name="javaRating" type="radio" value="1" class="star"/>
           <input name="javaRating" type="radio" value="2" class="star"/>
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of the question and the case of multiple "javaRatingDivs" this would work inside the checkbox click function:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('div').show();
```

.parent() gets the parent element
.next() gets the next sibling, such as the NEXT td
.find(selector) lets you find something within that sibling

This info is for when you get into the issues of multiple items and NOT having ID's to reference directly. In your above case, $('#javaRatingDiv').show(); would work great as patrick mentioned.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you Dan.  It worked great.  Appreciate the explanation as I am fairly new to JQuery.

Comment: Since this is what you're after: One thing, then, to keep in your toolbox is the .parents() function. If the 'td' isn't always a level above, something like this will work:
$(this).parents('td:first').next().find('div.classOfYourRateDiv').show();

Comment: +1 for the traversal example. I had a feeling that was what OP may have wanted, but was heading out the door. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `div` has an ID, you can access it directly.

```
$('#javaRatingDiv');
```

This will grab the `div` with ID 'javaRatingDiv'.

Comment: Thanks.  I am actually looking to access the DIV without the ID.  The ID is possibly going to be removed.  These are going to be loaded from a database and each section won't have a unique ID.  Is there anyway to access this using the DOM structure?  Maybe siblings?